# How to find the average of the three maximum values in a specific group in a moving window in Big Query?

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a data set as in the table below. I want to find the average of the maximum three values in a rolling 12 month window grouped by id.

```
id     date         value
id1    2020/01/01   500 
id1    2021/02/01   300  
id1    2021/03/01   150
id1    2021/08/01   100
id1    2021/12/01   400
id2    2020/01/01   50
id2    2020/02/01   900
id2    2021/12/01   100
```

So my expected output is:

```
id     date         value
id1    2020/01/01   500 
id1    2021/02/01   300  
id1    2021/03/01   225
id1    2021/08/01   183.33
id1    2021/12/01   283.33
id2    2020/01/01   50
id2    2020/02/01   500
id2    2021/12/01   100
```

I.e. for `id1` `2021/12/01`: (400+300+150)/3 = 283.33  which is the average of the three largest values in a rolling 12 month window for group ID1.

I managed to get to this point:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION avg_array(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
SELECT AVG(val) FROM(
SELECT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 3)
)
);

SELECT id, date, avg_array(val_arr)
FROM (
SELECT
id, date, ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER (
PARTITION BY id
ORDER BY id, date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 11 FOLLOWING
) as val_arr
FROM  `table` )
```

Which works, but I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Specifically, I can't figure out how to get the average of the maximum three from the OVER as well rather than creating a seperate function.

(If not possible to combine date window with finding maximum values, it would also be useful for me to know how to find the average of the maximum three in any `group by` group without creating a seperate function)

`

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id, date, 
  (select round(avg(value), 2) from (
     select value from t.arr value
     order by value desc 
     limit 3
  )) value
from (
  select *, array_agg(value) over last_12_month arr from table
  window last_12_month as (partition by id 
    order by 12 * (extract(year from date)) + extract(month from date)
     range between 11 preceding and current row
  )
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the year of the date in the “PARTITION BY id,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) “ statement is missing.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION avg_array(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
SELECT AVG(val) FROM(
SELECT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 3))
);
 
SELECT id, date, avg_array(val_arr)
FROM (
SELECT
id, date, ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER (
PARTITION BY id,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)
ORDER BY id, date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 11 FOLLOWING
) as val_arr
FROM  `table` )
order by id,date asc
```

Here, you can see a sample code to get the maximum 3 numbers of a group:

```
select id,AVG(value) as vg from (
select id,date,value from (
select id, date, value  from `table`
order by value desc) a limit 3
) b group by id
```

You can see more information about over function in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#compute_rank).